# How to play NSData audio or video in iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, video, uiwebview, nsdata

I need to present an audio or video content in iOS.

Unfortunately, I do not receive the audio/video as URL, but as `NSData` with content-type (MIME type).

It seems `UIWebView` does not play the audio/video data properly when using the `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`
only when using the `loadRequest:` (thanks Apple for this wonderful controller)

So I wanted to save the NSData to a temp file, but I don't have the file extension (just MIME type).

What is the best way to accomplish this?
Maybe implement an audio/video player using some other iOS controls?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need the extension to save it to a tempfile. Just save it w/o extension, and e. g. AVAudioPlayer will figure out from its contents what filetype it is.

Comment: I need to support both audio and video content, so it can solve only the audio part. Does using AVAudioPlayer means I need to implement my own "Player" with buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wants to know here is the solution:

You need to use [UTType functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/Reference/reference.html)
declared in a framework called MobileCoreServices.
The basic idea is to get the UTI from the MIME type, then get the extension from the UTI:

MIME-Type --> UTI --> file-extension.

An example of MIME-Type to UTI conversion can be found [here](http://ddeville.me/2011/12/mime-to-UTI-cocoa/).

Answer (score 0):

make a method that mapps the MIME type to the suitable extension

```
-(NSString *)getExtenstionFromMimeType:(NSString *)mimeType
{

   if ( [mimeType isEqualToString:@""video/mp4"] )
       return @"mp4"; 
   else if  ( ..... ) 
         and so on 

}
```

you can also use the MPVideoPlayerController to play audio video but you will also need the source media as a url or a local file path

Comment: This solution requires me to maintain a MIME to Extension map, and considering that there are many duplications of both file types and MIME types, it's a mess.